# insert database from view located in a different server

Tags: sql-server

I want to feed my database with data that i retrieve from a view that is located in a different server.

previously I inserted data in a table that's located in the same server as the view and I used this script :

```
   use databasename
   Go
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   INSERT INTO table1
   SELECT * FROM view1
```

but now I'm confused how to do it as they're not located in the same server.

anyone can help with this?

Comment: You need to create a server object called a "linked server" that defines a particular remote server and login. Then you can use it's login-available objects by using a 4-part convertion [LinkedServerName].Database.Schema.ViewName

Comment: If you have the other server set up as a linked server, you can just use 4 part naming convention. `SELECT {Columns} FROM Server.Database.Schema.Object;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by @EzLo, you can create linked server and alter your query 
to specify full route to your view.

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * 
FROM LINKED_SERVER.YOUR_DATABASE.OBJECT_SCHEMA.view1
```